# Accessing the list of list specific number elements and merging using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of list elements in that i have to access specific number elements and merge them using python code.

I have tried using list Comprehension but it is not working.

```py
myList = [['a:', 'b:', '4,80', 'c:', 'b:', '5,00', ':', '4,91', 'Pass'], ['a:', 'b:', '1,45', 'c:', 'b:', '1,55', 'd:', '1,51', 'Pass'], ['a:', 'b:', '-1,15', 'a:', 'b:', '-0,95', 'c:', '-1,07', 'Pass']]
test = [myList [i] for i in [2,5,7]]
            str1 = ''.join(test)
            remove = int(str1.replace(',',''))
            add_commas= "{:,}".format(remove)
            conv_list = add_commas.split(',')
            ac,ll,ut = conv_list[0],conv_list[1],conv_list[2]
            print(ac,ll,ut)
```

The expected output should be:

```
[[480,500,491],[145,155,151],[-115,-095,-107]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you gather up just the characters you want, then you can return them with a function like:

```
GOOD_CHARS = set('0123456789-+')

def to_number(num_str):
    return ''.join(c for c in num_str if c in GOOD_CHARS)
```

Then if you drop any empty strings you will get what you are after.

#### Test Code:

```
my_list = [['a:', 'b:', '4,80', 'c:', 'b:', '5,00', ':', '4,91', 'Pass'],
          ['a:', 'b:', '1,45', 'c:', 'b:', '1,55', 'd:', '1,51', 'Pass'],
          ['a:', 'b:', '-1,15', 'a:', 'b:', '-0,95', 'c:', '-1,07', 'Pass']]

print([[int(to_number(x)) for x in row if to_number(x)] for row in my_list])
```

#### Results:

```
[[480, 500, 491], [145, 155, 151], [-115, -95, -107]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    myList = [['a:', 'b:', '4,80', 'c:', 'b:', '5,00', ':', '4,91', 'Pass'],
      ['a:', 'b:', '1,45', 'c:', 'b:', '1,55', 'd:', '1,51', 'Pass'],
      ['a:', 'b:', '-1,15', 'a:', 'b:', '-0,95', 'c:', '-1,07', 'Pass']]
    result= []
    for sub_lst in myList:
        res=[]
        for i in sub_lst:
            if i.__contains__(','):
                res.append(int(i.replace(",","")))
        result.append(res)
    print(result)
    #[[480, 500, 491], [145, 155, 151], [-115, -95, -107]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution with `re` module:

```
myList = [['a:', 'b:', '4,80', 'c:', 'b:', '5,00', ':', '4,91', 'Pass'],
          ['a:', 'b:', '1,45', 'c:', 'b:', '1,55', 'd:', '1,51', 'Pass'],
          ['a:', 'b:', '-1,15', 'a:', 'b:', '-0,95', 'c:', '-1,07', 'Pass']]

import re
r = re.compile(r'[\d\-+]+')

out = [[int(i) for i in (''.join(r.findall(d)) for d in row) if i] for row in myList]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out, width=30)
```

Prints:

```
[[480, 500, 491],
 [145, 155, 151],
 [-115, -95, -107]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isdigit()` string method to check for number and then do `int()` to convert it to number

```
In [1]: myList = [['a:', 'b:', '4,80', 'c:', 'b:', '5,00', ':', '4,91', 'Pass'], ['a:', 'b
   ...: :', '1,45', 'c:', 'b:', '1,55', 'd:', '1,51', 'Pass'], ['a:', 'b:', '-1,15', 'a:',
   ...:  'b:', '-0,95', 'c:', '-1,07', 'Pass']]
In [2]: out = [[int(j.replace(',', '')) for j in i if j.replace(',', '').isdigit()] for i
...:  in myList]

In [3]: out 
Out[3]: [[480, 500, 491], [145, 155, 151], []]
```